# Change the background image property of body depending on which ID and class is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a site that has all of its pages basically "slide" around on the main landing page. So you basically start on a div with an ID of "main" that also has a class of "currentpage." If you click a nav menu item, the content slides away, and the next page's content slides into place. This new content's primary div would have a new id (let's say #about), and now the "currentpage" class is added to this div as well.

The thing is, the body tag has a background-image attached to it (it used to have a full screen video, but I set that to hide, and then there's this bg image behind it). I'd like to change the background image depending on which "page" you are on. At first, I set it up so that #about had a background-image set up, and so forth for the rest of the page IDs. The thing about this is that the content of the primary div is padded a whole bunch, so you would see the specified #about background image, but then you'd actually also still see that original image from the body tag behind it.

Thus, I'd like to change the actual body tag's background image property depending on which ID you're on.

I figured some means of checking if you're on a specified ID, as well as if the class for that div is set to "currentpage" would be step 1, with step 2 then changing the background image if that condition is true.

Here is what I have tried so far, to no avail:

Attempt 1:

```
if ($this.is('#about')) { 
$('.bgimage').css({"background":"url(imageurlhere)"});
```

}

This didn't do anything.

Next, I found [this old SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565075/jquery-if-element-has-class-do-this) and tried to modify it just to see it in action to know if I was on the right path. Here's what I used:

Attempt 2:

```
if ($("#about").hasClass("currentpage")) {
$('#about').css({"background-color":"red"});
```

}

Unfortunately, this also didn't cause anything differently) when I went to About.

And yes, I had cleared cache out each time, and manually even went to the JS file to ensure it had the new code blocks each time.

**Edit**
Here is the basic page format:

```
<body class="video">
<div class="preload">Whole lot of stuff in here for a preload overlay</div>
<nav>Nav is here</nav>
<main>
    <div id="pt-main" class="pt-perspective ">
        <div class="page-1 currentpage" id="main"></div>
        <div class="page-2" id="about"></div>
        <div class="page-3" id="services"></div>
        <div class="page-4" id="portfolio"></div>
        <div class="page-5" id="contact"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

The "currentpage" class will go to a different div if the corresponding link in the nav is clicked. So, click About in the nav, currentpage class drops from #main and ends up in same div as #about

And then the CSS for the body tag is as follows:

```
.video {
background: url(../img/video_bg.jpg);
background-size: cover;
```

}

I basically want to make it so that background (image) of .video changes when you end up on #about, #services, #portfolio, etc.

**TL;DR**
Can anyone help me with this code block? How do I check if an div with a specific ID also has a class, and then modify the .bgimage CSS to change its background?

**Edit 2**:
I came up with a workaround for this. Here's what I did:
1) I set the overall background color to #000, removed the original bg-image altogether, and actually restored a full-screen video I'd previously hid
2) I edited each nav menu item to have a hidevid class, except for the Home link, which I made showvid
3) I created CSS for each "page" ID (ie #about {background-image: url(image);}
4) I created a new CSS class: .hidethis {display: none;}
5) I then implemented the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hidevid").click(function(){
    $("video").addClass("hidethis");
});
$(".showvid").click(function(){
    $("video").removeClass("hidethis");
});
```

});

What this does is set the background to black, but that's not seen on the landing ("home") page, just the video. However, clicking a nav menu item will "slide" the next "page" into view, displaying its background image and changing the video to have a display: none property, basically hiding it and the extra content (the nav) just has a black background behind it.

Comment: Can you show the html and css for this please?

Comment: What is not working?
`$('body').css({backgroundImage: 'url(...)'});`

Comment: @MiriamSalzer - I updated the original post with the html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround for this. Here's what I did:
1) I set the overall background color to #000, removed the original bg-image altogether, and actually restored a full-screen video I'd previously hid
2) I edited each nav menu item to have a hidevid class, except for the Home link, which I made showvid
3) I created CSS for each "page" ID (ie #about {background-image: url(image);}
4) I created a new CSS class: .hidethis {display: none;}
5) I then implemented the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hidevid").click(function(){
    $("video").addClass("hidethis");
});
$(".showvid").click(function(){
    $("video").removeClass("hidethis");
});
});
```

What this does is set the background to black, but that's not seen on the landing ("home") page, just the video. However, clicking a nav menu item will "slide" the next "page" into view, displaying its background image and changing the video to have a display: none property, basically hiding it and the extra content (the nav) just has a black background behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla JavaScript (pure JavaScript), you can check if a div has a particular class name and based on the results, change the css by doing this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('about');
var y = document.querySelector('.bgimage');

if (x.classList.contains('currentpage')){ // if #about has "currentpage" class, run the following
    x.style.background = 'red';               //change background-color of #about to red
    y.style.background = 'url(imageurlhere)'; // change background-image of .bgimage
}
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/nqjypevh/10/

---

Comment: This looks really good, and makes sense to me, but it didn't end up working in the site for me.

Comment: Hmm.... Not really sure what is going on but did/can you try keeping the above code in the bottom of the page above the closing body tag? If after doing that, it still doesn't work, refresh the page and check the browser console by pressing F12. If there are any errors in the console, can you copy them in the comments here.

Comment: I tried it just above the end body tag, but it didn't work. There wasn't any error pertaining to it in the console (only error was related to a Maps plugin missing its API key)

Comment: Is your site live? If yes, can you give me a link to it and I'll check it out.

Comment: I found a workaround - I posted what I ended up doing in the original post. Thank you, though!

Comment: Sweet. Glad you found a solution for your issue! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

your codes is wrong. true usage is this.

```
css('background-color','red')
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m making a whole lot of assumptions and guesses. You only showed one css class. From the description it sounds like the problem is actually using CSS to cover the background, and that if it weren’t for that, there would be no need to change the class on the body. The basic solution, move the initial background from the body to the #main div, move the padding to the .page-1, .page-2 etc. divs. Also, if the background images are transparent also give a background-color.

I’m assuming the nav does not have a background image and stays put. I’m also assuming you already have the sliding of the sections in place, I didn’t show that but instead just a simple display none/block just to keep it simple. I also didn’t show the js (but you shouldn’t need to change the body class.) I also left the html alone.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

main {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
  background-size: cover;
}

.pt-perspective > div {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  padding: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: aqua;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
  display: none; /* or positioned off screen, wherever you already have it */
}

.pt-perspective .currentpage {
  display: block;
}

.pt-perspective .page-1 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800?image=1);
}
.pt-perspective .page-2 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800?image=2);
}
.pt-perspective .page-3 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800?image3);
}
.pt-perspective .page-4 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800?image=4);
}
.pt-perspective .page-5 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600?image=5);
}
```

```html
<body class="video">
<!-- <div class="preload">Whole lot of stuff in here for a preload overlay</div> -->
<nav>Nav is here</nav>
<main>
    <div id="pt-main" class="pt-perspective ">
        <div class="page-1 currentpage" id="main"></div>
        <div class="page-2" id="about"></div>
        <div class="page-3" id="services"></div>
        <div class="page-4" id="portfolio"></div>
        <div class="page-5" id="contact"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```